# 0-1-2 Matrix from a table heatmap

Tags: mysql, bash, matrix

My goal is to get a 0-1-2-Matrix  from Informations provided in a mysql table.

Example:

Table 'Dom'

```
Origin|Species      |  Domain  

KMT1 |  blabla_1234 |  Kringel

KMT1 |  blabla_1234 |  Helix  

KMT1 |  wobble_4556 |  Kringel 

KMT2 |  blabla_1234  | Helix  

KMT2 | piffi_876    |  Kringel
```

Now I want to have the following Matrix: On the x-Axis will be all Species - 
Something like this:

```
blabla_1234 | wobble_4556 | piffi_876
```

On the y-Axis will be all Domains from Table 'Dom' BUT they have to be grouped by their according KMT ('Origin').
For example the y-Axis would look like this:

```
KMT1 Helix

KMT1 Kringel

KMT2 Helix

KMT2 Kringel
```

The Result should be this:
[image: Wanted heatmap]

Orange means that both Domain and Original-Protein exist in the given species. Yellow means that only the protein is found in the species, but not the domain.
I barely just learned how to used MySQL and I never wrote scripts. Can you give me a hint with what **program**/script I could do this task?

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Given that your Dom table only contains the positives and not the negatives, you'll want to generate the negatives so that your output table can map them.

This query will get you all the possible combinations of origin, domain and species:

```
SELECT ds.domain, os.origin, ss.species FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM Dom) ds
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT origin FROM Dom) os
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT species FROM Dom) ss
```

So, to get the "expression values" for each combination, including the negatives, do this:

```
SELECT completelist.domain, completelist.origin, completelist.species, 
       COALESCE(Dom.species, FALSE) AS found
FROM
    (SELECT ds.domain, os.origin, ss.species
     FROM 
          (SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM Dom) ds
          CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT DISTINCT origin FROM Dom) os
          CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT DISTINCT species FROM Dom) ss
    ) AS completelist
LEFT JOIN Dom ON (completelist.domain = Dom.domain &&
                  completelist.origin = Dom.origin &&
                  completelist.species = Dom.species)
```

Once you have an [array](/questions/tagged/array) of records from your database, you could output then as an [html](/questions/tagged/html) table.  You would style (using [css](/questions/tagged/css)) the `<td>` elements according to the value of expressionvalue. So your output would look something like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Origin</th>
     <th>Domain</th> 
     <th>Blahbla_1234</th>
     <th>wobble_4556</th>
     <th>piffi_876</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <th>KMT1</th>
     <th>Kringel</th> 
     <td class='bothexist'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class='bothexist'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class='onlyprotein'>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
     <th>KMT1</th>
     <th>Helix</th> 
     <td class='bothexist'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class='onlyprotein'>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr> 
   <!-- etc. -->
 </tbody>
 <tfoot></tfoot>
<table>
```

The part that is fiddly is reorganizing the data that comes from your query into a structure from which it is easy to output a table.

In any event, while you could use a shell script to do all this, you'd probably have an easier time using a higher level language. [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) has traditionally been used in bioinformatics and there are many nice libraries available including, perhaps most importantly [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page). [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) are popular too. [php](/questions/tagged/php) is a very popular and generic language particularly adapted to websites and considered very easy to learn (but many programmers object to its various laxities).

I hope this points you in a useful direction.

Comment: Hi there! I dont quite understand what is meant with the expressionvalue table.

Comment: @Wicked_sue: I made up a table since you didn't say where you were storing the information about whether a particular domain/origin/species combination was positive for protein at the species level, the domain level or both. If you edit your question to contain that information I can give you a better answer.

Comment: That information is already included in the Table "Dom". You have the protein, the domain and the species. One Protein has more than 1 Domain. Are you familiar with bioinformatics?

Comment: @Wicked_sue: So you're saying that the *presense* of a particular domain/origin/species combination *is* the expression value? That's doable, but more fiddly since you'll need to output dummy data when a particular combination does not exist in your table. Otherwise you won't see any of the negatives.  I've been programming apps to deal with bioinformatic data for about 10 years.

Comment: @Wicked_sue: I've edited my answer to suit my new understanding of your data.

Comment: The Problem now is that I get a syntax error at the select subquery " (SELECT ds.domain, os.origin, ss.species
     FROM " :(

Comment: @Wicked_sue: what is the text of your error message? I've replaced the `CASE...` with `COALESCE...` on the off chance that will make a difference.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN Dom.species THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS found (SELECT domain_name, q' at line 1

Comment: When I use "case" this is the error: "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT domain_name, query_prot_id, taxon_schema FROM (SELECT DISTINCT domain_na' at line 1

Comment: @Wicked_sue: it looks like I forgot one of the `FROM`s when I was cut and pasting.  Try it now.